# Group of friends project % split problem

Tags: professionalism, management, project-management

Recently me with a group of friends (group of 3) have started a web page, we have decided that the % (future benefits and expenses) of the project will be 42.5%/42.5%/15%, despite the fact that the last participant (15%) has already messed it up, and has made us lose several days of work, he has told us that since he only has 15%, he will only offer 15% interest on the project.

How can the other two colleagues deal with this type of attitude? Is he right? Since he only has 15% of business, is it logical that he only offers 15% of the time to the project compared to us? **How can I tell him that despite having 15%, he should give his 100% without seeming unfair?**

I am an empathic person and I feel that in his position I would also feel left out, but I'm hoping he understands that since the idea was not his, he will not be taking the same as us (the other two)

Extra info:
The project is just starting, we barely have a week of worked-time, so we can't pay the 3rd friend a salary.

Second edit:
The project idea was between member 1 and me, then after we thought how everything would work we simply invited the 3rd member to the group, we didn't saw much interest from him so we decided to kick him, but as he was our friend and told us he would work we re-invited him back, and gave them the % of project.

Answering Benjamin, the 3rd member is web-designer, so we followed up an advice of his to make the page with the puglin he knew, turns up that plugin required a 65€ version that we didn't bought cause 3rd member told us with a 3€ bought was enough, so we had to reset the work and start again without that plugin.

Last update: I have realized the injustice of what I was asking for, I apologize for my lack of experience, we will offer that last participant an equal percentage, and if the project does not work as 3 it does not matter, I value more the relationship with the friend than the project, thanks to all!

Comment: how has he messed up?
why does the messup mean he get's approx 1/3 of what you others get?
how do you evaluate his future contribution?

Comment: `if (businessPartners === friends || family && enumeration != fair && humanGreed == true) {businessModel = false}`

Comment: @Benjamin edited to answer

Comment: Why are the downvotes tho? Its a legit question, if im asking is because I want to know your answers, just tell me to delete and I will if you find the question inappropriate.

Comment: what are your skills, and your future contributions?
also in relating to the project.
e.g. you have a heavy datascience project, some website display is just a minor value add.
Or, you have a heavy datascience project, but a great easy to understand display is like your main selling point.
The value of a skilled webdesigner will change depending on what you do.

Comment: When and how was the 42.5 / 42.5 / 15 split negotiated? It sounds like this third participant accepted the 15% share because they thought they would only be expected to contribute 15%. And now you're "renegotiating" by telling them that even though they're paid 15%, they should actually contribute 33%.

Comment: None of us are experts, we are learing by making, even though he is a Web-Designer I doubt he knows much more than the rest, as we all studied similar things, so even though he has a superior-grade on Web-design lets say we value the work equaly.

Comment: @Stef It was not negotiated, we negotiated between the member 1 and 2, but the % is changable, and we told him.

Comment: Well, it really sounds this is just an issue caused by lack of communication. The three of you should sit down around a table and make sure you are all on the same page both regarding the profit split and the work split.

Comment: @Stef Yeah, I guess we should, as Benjamin said maybe im overvaluating the Idea too much, also, I didn't even want to have a 3rd member, but the situation kinda turned into that, as we were talking about the project when the 3rd member joined, but again, thats my fault, as I should have just said no and moved on. I guess I'm asking for professionalism when I don't even have it

Comment: @Erik Managing a business or being "professional" is a skill that is not really taught at school and that you will keep learning, and making mistakes in, your whole life. It's okay. Those mistakes are not irredeemable. And more often than not they can be fixed by better communication. Just make sure you don't lose your friends over this.

Comment: Yeah, when we kicked that friend I was afraid losing him would happend, thats a reason for the re-invite, I'm just now stuck in this akward situation were I cant kick my friend and I dont see the bussines viable short-mid term between 3 people. @Stef

Comment: Well, then you can say that. Sit down all three at a table, and explain exactly that: you don't expect that there will be enough money to split between 3 people, and you expect that 2 people can manage the whole workload. Your friend might understand.

Comment: Is it a project for a company where you all get paid ? Or is it a personal project for a startup that you guys found together ?

Comment: Personal project @Job_September_2020

Comment: Always remember: Ideas are cheap! EVERYONE and their mother has them. As a software developer (web, app, game and windows) I hear million dollar ideas almost daily. The perfect game or app, the website that will be facebook 2.0 or the windows application every company needs. The developing work would be almost always 100% me and that is the most of the work. I wouldnt give anyone anything for just an idea, maybe a small share. Usually you can get that idea yourself if you just try to find (or create) a problem that needs to be solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am an empathic person and I feel that in his position I would also feel left out, but I'm hoping he understands that since the idea was not his, he will not be taking the same as us (the other two)

people with ideas overvalue ideas and undervalue the work required to make ideas valuable. you have put barely anytime into the idea, so you will need to put in some serious amount of time to actually extract value out of the idea. Your friend realizes this. In this process, he might have several ideas that greatly increase the value of the base idea. Or his brain helps the 3 of you to improve the idea in a team effort.

So him getting just about a 1/3 of you seems unfair to him, because it is.
If you value his input and you value your idea, discuss what a fair amount would be.
maybe a 35/35/30 split would work.
maybe you have to do a true 1/3*3 split, and you agree to a certain amount of money you get as onetime payment once the company takes off to compensate for the idea.

Also, I don't see why him messing up should affect his share.
All 3 of you will mess up in the future, all 3 of you hopefully learn.
And the percent he gains should be measured by the value he adds in the future, not the past.
By giving him way less, you tell him you value his future input way less.
Without knowing any details about the kind of work he will do, that sounds unfair. You would need to provide details that his work is actually worth less than yours. In a vacuum, I doubt you have these details.

To sum up: You should check your own expectations, what you ask is impossible.

Comment: You are right, im being unfair.

Comment: @Erik I'm happy with your reflection and also humbleness to acknowledged you handled it unfairly. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 5):

You can't - what you're asking *is* unfair. If you're not going to give him an equal share of the equity, pay him a salary.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific about the project status, right now we are starting, we barelly have a week of work, we can't pay a salary.

Comment: In that case, you don't have a viable business model.

Comment: We don't, we will discuss it group-wise and figure it out, thanks!